# Visual Studio throwing errors for node_modules that contain a tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In my project I have a `tsconfig.json` which sits in the project root. However, Visual Studio is throwing a number of errors about the `tsconfig.json` found in other packages, like so:

[image: Screenshot of errors in Visual Studio]

`node_modules` is excluded from the project and I don't get these errors when using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not sure if it has unwanted consequences for you; https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846164/543549

Comment: Try to avoid node_modules in your tsconfig file check this link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634361/how-to-force-tsc-to-ignore-node-modules-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the node_modules folder and rebuild your angular project.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the node_modules

add this to your tsconfig.json

"skipLibCheck": true

then build