# Visual Studio 2022: How to disable TypeScript errors coming from node_modules?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, node-modules

I'm getting hundreds of errors from files in my node_modules folder for this project. How do I stop these from filling my Visual Studio error section? I feel like I'm missing a config file perhaps but unsure... The project does not use TypeScript itself.

[image: examples of errors in VS project's error list]

My `package.json` file looks like this:

[image: package.json screenshot]

Comment: Enable `skipLibCheck` in your tsconfig.

Comment: Woah.. People use VS for js/ts development? Why not vscode?

Comment: @vr. I will have to create a `tsconfig` file then. Anything else I need in that file as standard? As mentioned in the question I don't actually have a TypeScript element to the project

Comment: @zerdox I'm not trying to use VS for JS/TS development. It's just picking up all these errors from the node_modules folder for the project. VS Code is 100% the better editor for JS/TS files

Comment: @GeorgeFeakes as I know you can also use jsconfig. You can also try to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73423322/11858171

Comment: @zerdox sadly I thought this had worked but then a week later the errors have appeared again in Visual Studio while the folder and sub folders are still hidden...